# Different results using ST_Length and ST_LengthSpheroid in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a 3D MULTILINESTRING geometry in my database contains lat/long and EPSG:4326:

```
'MULTILINESTRING Z ((50.9872438056729 35.0857686001374 906.97,...)
```

and I calculated the length through two methods:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()

_spheroid = 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
cur.execute("SELECT ST_LengthSpheroid(geom,'{spheroid}')/1000 from ...;".format(spheroid=_spheroid))
#68.030 KM

cur.execute("SELECT ST_Length(geom, false), id from ...;")
#68.001 KM
```

Where does this difference come from?

Comment: You say WGS84 but what is your exact CRS? A EPSG code is enough if you used that.

Comment: And doesn't https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16271/st-distance-versus-st-distancespheroid look like a duplicate?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I edited it. It's EPSG:4326.

Comment: @bugmenot123 The link you sent me was helpful. Should I delete mine?

Comment: Sweet! Deleting is a bit too much in my opinion, I think you could mark your question as duplicate if you try to "close" it. That would keep it available if someone else has the same question. Thanks!

Comment: @bugmenot123 I flagged it as duplicate.